# validating dynamic form (single fields, grouped fields)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

Im trying to create a dynamic form with a jQuery validation.
All functions for validate are already set, but I just can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Lets assume We have 3 fields:

```
<input .... class='validateme name' />
<input .... class='validateme email' />
<input .... class='validateme phone' />
```

now with jQuery I go through all inputs with validateme class, and validate them according to second class parameter (if field fails validation, error message is added after the element). This is quite obvious, but now I would like to group last 2 fields:

```
<input .... class='validateme name' />
<input .... class='validateme email grouped group_a' />
<input .... class='validateme phone grouped group_a' />
```

Now the difference is with last 2 fields - only one of them needs to be filled correctly.
And because form is dynamic, user can create names of the groups by himself, I just need to creare jQuery function that is universal, and if element have class `grouped` then only one of the fields needs to be correct.

There might be situation like this:

```
<input .... class='validateme email grouped group_a' />
<input .... class='validateme phone grouped group_a' />
<input .... class='validateme name grouped group_b' />
<input .... class='validateme name grouped group_b' />
```

Any ideas how to deal with that would be great :).

Comment: Can we see your validation code (javascript/jquery)?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( valid(name)) && (valid(email) || valid(phone)) ) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your function here that is universal. You can use the .hasClass() function to see if the element has that class

```
$.each($('.validateme'),function(key,val)
{
    var groupedTrue = false;
    //some code

    if ($(val).hasClass('grouped') && isValid(key))
    {
         groupedTrue = true;
    }
}
```

With this code, you can check the groupedTrue var to make sure at least one grouped object is valid

Comment: Thats something closer that what I used to be, but still - if there are more than one group, this will only work on default 'grouped' class, and will not work with different grouped elements. The problem is that there might be few different groups, and in each group only one element need to be valid.